# Connecting IdentityServer4 with Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, identityserver4

As one of my requirements, I am supposed to connect the IdentitySever with an Active Directory with existing users and claims. So far I managed to create an App Registration in the Azure Portal. So I have an `Appication ID` and also configured an `API Key`. Further, I have a list of Endpoints:

```
https://login.windows.net/{ad_guid}/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml
https://login.windows.net/{ad_guid}/wsfed
https://login.windows.net/{ad_guid}/saml2
https://login.windows.net/{ad_guid}/saml2
https://graph.windows.net/{ad_guid}
https://login.windows.net/{ad_guid}/oauth2/token
https://login.windows.net/{ad_guid}/oauth2/authorize
```

I can get the OpenID configuration with

```
https://login.windows.net/{ad_guid}/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

According to the [documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapp-dotnet) I should now configure the endpoint like this:

```cs
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

var uri = "https://login.windows.net/{0}";
var instance = configuration["AzureAD:Instance"];
var authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, uri, instance);

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    DisplayName = "Azure Active Directory",
    AuthenticationScheme = "AzureAD",
    SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
    ClientId = configuration["AzureAD:AppId"],
    Authority = authority, 
    Scope = {"openid", "email"}
});
```

For some reason this is not working. Any ideas what I might have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently, I had it almost right. here is my solution:

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = 
        IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme,
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true
});
```

```
    public static OpenIdConnectOptions CreateAzureAdOptions(X509Certificate2 certificate2, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        return new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            DisplayName = "Azure Active Directory",
            AuthenticationScheme = "Azure",
            ClientId = configuration["OpenId:AzureAD:AppId"],
            Authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.windows.net/{0}", configuration["OpenId:AzureAD:Instance"]),
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false
            },
            // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims
            Scope = {"openid", "email", "roles", "groups"},
            Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnRemoteFailure = context => HandleRemoteFailure(context)
            },
            SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme
        };
    }

    private static Task HandleRemoteFailure(FailureContext context)
    {
        Log.Error(context.Failure, "Azure AD Remote Failure");
        context.Response.Redirect("/accessdenied");
        context.HandleResponse();
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

Comment: Under configuration["OpenId:AzureAD:Instance"], does the value in "Instance" have your tenant name?

Comment: it's the GUID of the AzureAD instance